How to handle "once" in a sentence?
Does "once" mean the same as "after"?

When I sleep she cooks- it happens at the same time

After I sleep she cooks- cooking happens later when I don't sleep anymore

Once I sleep she cooks- does it mean the same as 2?



cambridge dictionary Once as a conjunction We use once as a conjunction meaning ‘as soon as’ or ‘after’: Once I’ve picked Megan up, I’ll call you.  My boss is a nice man once you get to know him. But why is it always sleeping and cooking with your examples?

Does it matter? Could you explain the 3 one?

A problem with this question is that cooking, and especially sleeping, aren't single events, but processes. It's unclear what is meant by "once" or "after" or "when" in these examples. Better examples w\could be "After I wake up, she starts cooking.", or "Once I am awake, she will start cooking."

Of course it matters! It's been pointed out before (possibly several times) that when you're asking about the temporal relationship between two verb-based clauses, it's not helpful that one or both of the verbs are inherently imprecise and/or the two clauses don't naturally reflect event sequences in the real world. For example, there's a very common sequence After I slept, she cooked me breakfast, and because you're not a native speaker, it would be perfectly natural for anyone reading your example #3 to assume that's what you had in mind (pointlessly switched to present tense).

These are not idiomatic English sentences. We have seen very similar ones here in the past few months using the verbs sleep and cook and come.  Are these sentences coming from a book that teaches English by any chance? If so, throw the book in the trashcan.

Same old questions being asked under yet another different name?

What @KateBunting said. Possible duplicate of Different conjunctions, which asks about the equally bizarre When/if you cook I will arrive, Once you cook I will arrive, Once I slept she broke in.

No - 3 doesn't mean the same as 2.

"After I sleep" could mean after you have finished sleeping, ie when you have woken up she begins cooking. We'd avoid this confusion by saying "after I have fallen asleep, she cooks", or more likely "while I sleep, she cooks".

"Once I sleep" could mean after you have fallen asleep, is she cooks while you sleep. If that isn't what you mean, and you actually do want to say she cooks after you finish sleeping you could say "once I have slept, she cooks".



When you say " 'Once I sleep' [could mean] after you have fallen asleep..." do you mean "[could be intended to mean]..."; that is, if one were trying to guess what a non-native speaker was trying to say, a native speaker might suppose they meant that?
